# AngularJS ng-click does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-click

Here's my code (i already added angular):

```
<body ng-app="clickExample" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="choice = 1">
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("clickExample", []);
    app.controller('ExampleController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
        $scope.apiCall = function () {
            alert('ciao');
        };
    }]);
    </script>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="apiCall()">Ciao</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

EDIT: here's the entire html (i also have a style-sheet and other JS libraries but i don't think they're relevant).

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Network | Social Network</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 10pt arial;
        }

        #mynetwork {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            background: #F3F3F3;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vis.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="apiLogic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myModule.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="stileTabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> </head>

<body ng-app="clickExample" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="choice = 1">
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("clickExample", []);
        app.controller('ExampleController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
            $scope.showAlert = function () {
                alert("This is an example of ng-click");
            };
            $scope.apiCall = function () {
                alert('ciao');
            };
    }]);
    </script>
    <div ng-class="{selected: choice == 1, unselected: choice != 1}">
        <button class="tab" type="button" ng-click="choice=1">Cerca per nome</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="{selected: choice == 2, unselected: choice != 2}">
        <button class="tab" type="button" ng-click="choice=2">Cerca per ID</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="{selected: choice == 3, unselected: choice != 3}">
        <button class="tab" type="button" ng-click="choice=3">Rankings</button>
    </div>
    <div id="info" ng-show="choice==1"> Nome:
        <input type="text" id="nodeNameTxt">
        <br/> Data:
        <input type="text" id="dateTxt">
        <br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="gnbn()">Cerca nodo</button>
        <br/> </div>
    <div ng-show="choice==2"> Id:
        <input type="text" id="nodeIdTxt">
        <br/> Data:
        <input type="text" id="dateIdTxt">
        <br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="gnbid()">Cerca nodo</button>
        <br/> </div>
    <div ng-show="choice==3"> Limite:
        <input type="text" id="rankLimitTxt">
        <br/> Data:
        <input type="text" id="rankDateTxt">
        <br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="grank()">Ottieni classifica</button>
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="ExampleController.apiCall()">Ciao</button>
    </div>
    <div id="mynetwork" ng-hide="choice==3">
        <div class="vis network-frame" style="position: relative; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                -webkit-user-select: none; 
                touch-action: pan-y; 
                -webkit-user-drag: none; 
                -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
                width: 100%; 
                height: 100%;">
            <canvas width="1000" height="600" style="position: relative;
                       -webkit-user-select: none;
                       touch-action: pan-y;
                       -webkit-user-drag: none;
                       -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 100%;
                       height: 100%;"> </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When i click on the button nothing happens, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: angular version used

Comment: Have you load agular.js in your page??

Comment: `app.controller('ExampleController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {` order of arguments in the controller - You are injecting `$http` service first then `$scope`

Comment: Yes, i added <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script> (i also included $http in the correct order but nothing changed)

Comment: put all code plz, ur code works https://jsbin.com/vuwexarupu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: remove `ExampleController.` from `ng-click`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its working , From your ng-click ,Remove `ExampleController`

correct :  `<button ng-click="apiCall()">Ciao</button>`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="clickExample" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="choice = 1">
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("clickExample", []);
    app.controller('ExampleController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
        $scope.apiCall = function () {
            alert('ciao');
        };
    }]);
    </script>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="apiCall()">Ciao</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <button ng-click="apiCall()">Ciao</button> .Remove ExampleController from ng-click

Comment: Now it's working, i don't know what happened because i added the ExampleController.apiCall() in a second moment

Comment: Added the same in answer also

Answer (score 0):

You should add **$http** in `app.controller`

```
<body ng-app="clickExample" ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="choice = 1">
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("clickExample", []);
    app.controller('ExampleController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
        $scope.apiCall = function () {
            alert('ciao');
        };
    }]);
    </script>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="apiCall()">Ciao</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.

put the script  ...  after the import of angular script, because you are trying to use angular before import it.

For instance:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('clickExample', []);
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http,$scope) {
    $scope.apiCall = function () {
        alert('ciao');
    };
}]);
</script>
```

It will make your code work.

Comment: At the moment I have posted, nobody has given this answer.